# How do I get the values assigned to the Correct and Total numbers to update when the user inputs their answer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a Python file that when run, opens a window for simple addition practice. It asks the user for their input, and if the total is correct will output "Right!" and "Oops!" for incorrect. Below all of this is a counter that keeps track of the correct number out of the total. However, at the moment, those numbers both remain zero when user enters their input. What kind of changes would need to be made under the ClicktheButton1 function in order to get this program properly functioning? Thanks.

The output would end up looking like "2 out 4 correct" in the window, updating after each new problem is solved.

```
from tkinter import *
import random as rn 
window = Tk()
window.geometry('350x350')
window.title("C200")
x = rn.randint(0,100)
y = rn.randint(0,100)
correct, incorrect = 0,0

myLabel = Label(window, text="{0}+{1}=".format(x,y), font=("Arial Bold", 15))
myLabel.grid(column=0, row=0)

myLable2 = Label(window, text = "",font=("Arial Bold", 15))
myLable2.grid(column=0, row=5)

mylabel3 = Label(window,text = "0 out of 0 correct",font=("Arial Bold", 15)) 
mylabel3.grid(column=0, row=10)

mytxt = Entry(window, width=12)
mytxt.grid(column=1,row=0)

def ClicktheButton1():


    global x
    global y

    global correct
    global incorrect


    myguess = int(mytxt.get())

    if x + y == myguess:
        myLable2.configure(text = "Right!")
        correct += 1
    else:
        myLable2.configure(text = "Oops!")
        incorrect += 1



    x = rn.randint(0,100)
    y = rn.randint(0,100)
    mytxt.focus()
    mytxt.delete(0,END)
    myLabel.configure(text = "{0}+{1}=".format(x,y))

btn1 = Button(window, text="check", command = ClicktheButton1)
btn1.grid(column=0, row=7)

def ClicktheButton2():
    window.destroy()

btn1 = Button(window, text="Quit", command = ClicktheButton2)
btn1.grid(column=400, row=400)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: you have to change text in `mylabel3` in the same why as you change text in `myLabel` - I don't know why you have problem with this. `mylabel3.configure(text = "{0} of {1} correct".format(correct, correct+incorrect))`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change text in `mylabel3` in the same why as you change text in `myLabel` - and even in the same place. I don't know why you have problem with this.

```
 myLabel.configure(text = "{0}+{1}=".format(x,y))

 mylabel3.configure(text="{0} of {1} correct".format(correct, correct+incorrect))
```